# Alternative to setTimeout in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, settimeout, ngrx

I am dispatching the data to [ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/store). After that I want to scroll to a specific `div`, which is using this data from store.

```
@ViewChild('datalist') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef; 

this.store.dispatch(new SetClientSearchResultsAction(filteredData));

setTimeout(() => {
this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior:'smooth', block: 'start'});
 }, 300);
```

Below is the HTML div.

```
<div  #datalist id="mydata" *ngIf="clientSearchResults$ | async  as searchResults" 
class = 'result'>
  <p> hellooo</p>
</div>
```

I am getting the scroll at my div after dispatching the data to store. But I do not want to use `setTimeout`. It is **unnecessarily waiting for 300 milliseconds**. Is there any **alternative way to do that** ? I just want to scroll to my `div`, when my data is dispatched or ngif condition got fulfilled.

Below is the constructor of my component where I am getting the value from Store.

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _clientService: ClientService) {
    this.clientSearchResults$ = this.store.select('searchResults');
  }
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `scrollIntoView` is an experimental feature not supported by all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView. See the Browser compatibility of the provided link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Lifecycle hook, `AfterViewInit` Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: But. I have to set the scroll into div, how it will impact, I use the afterview init or init.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways with **RXJS**

**Option 1** - with  `asapScheduler`

```
asapScheduler.schedule(() => { // Your Code });
```

[Link](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asapScheduler)

**Option 2** - with `interval`

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

  interval(0).pipe(take(1),
   ).subscribe(value => { // Your Code });
```

[Link](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval)

**Option 3** - With `Promise`

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => { // Your Code });
```

The Optimum way will be with **Option 1** as it is made to avoid `setTimeout(deferredTask, 0)`

From the RxJS docs for `asapScheduler`:

> asap scheduler will do its best to minimize time between end of
> currently executing code and start of scheduled task. This makes it
> best candidate for performing so called "deferring". Traditionally
> this was achieved by calling setTimeout(deferredTask, 0), but that
> technique involves some (although minimal) unwanted delay.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that `clientSearchResults$` will emit a new value when dispatching `SetClientSearchResultsAction`, you can subscribe to `clientSearchResults$` in your component and initiate the scrolling from there.

```
ngOnInit() {
  clientSearchResults$
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior:'smooth', block: 'start'});
  });
}
```

Comment: I have added the constructor code as well, where I am setting the value in clientSearchResults$. Can you please tell me now, what changes, do I need to do?

Comment: I have tried this thing as well, in the subscribe also,when I am using without settimeout, it is not working. And when I put setTimeout, I am getting scroll to my div.

Comment: Try putting it in `ngAfterViewInit` as Rahul Sharma suggests.